# External Dependencies in Netbeans

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, netbeans, netbeans-7

I created a custom actions project in Visual Studio 2010, it set up external dependencies by default. Now I am migrating the project to NetBeans. What do I need to keep in mind as I migrate, and how do I configure external dependencies in NetBeans?